# Detect application close based on app user's name

Tags: powershell, crash, windows

been trying to create script to detect user's application crash. (Assume the computer is used by multiple users)

so far only managed to come out below code to query the application (based on user name) only but not app close or crash

```
gwmi -query "select * from win32_process where name='calc.exe'" | %{if($_.GetOwner().User -eq 'myUser'){
    #do something when app crash
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Register-WmiEvent`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849840.aspx) cmdlet to register an event with the [`Win32_ProcessStopTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394376(v=vs.85).aspx) event class.

The `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` doesn't have a `GetOwner()` method, but you can use your current code to gather the Process ID's of the processes you're interested in, and use those in your event query:

```
$UserName = 'myUser'
$ProcessName = 'calc.exe'
$PIDFilters = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='$ProcessName'" |Where-Object {
    $_.GetOwner().User -eq $UserName
} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId |ForEach-Object {
    "ProcessId={0}" -f $_
}

$WmiFilter = $PIDFilters -join " OR "
```

Now, you have a `$WmiFilter` that looks something like this:

```
ProcessId=2468 OR ProcessId=11576 OR ProcessId=5426
```

You can use that in a WMI query:

```
$WmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ($WmiFilter)"
```

And finally register the event with `Register-WmiEvent`:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query $WmiQuery -SourceIdentifier CalcStopEvent -Action {
    $TraceEvent = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent
    if($TraceEvent.ExitStatus -ne 0){
        # The process didn't exit with success/noerror
        # Send many emails!
        # Sound the klaxon!
        # Call the fire brigade!
        # or, whatever you feel like ...
    }
}
```

Comment: getting the error
`Register-WmiEvent : Unparsable query.`

Comment: Well, yes, if no instances of the process with the owner `myuser` are found, the WMI query becomes unparsable. Error handling in this case is very simple: `if($WmiFilter){ Register-WmiEvent}else{write-warning "no calc.exe processes found"}`

Comment: getting `Register-WmiEvent : Access denied ` instead if process is found